# Cannot load an image from a remote url

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried many solutions for this problem before posting but somehow I didn't succeed.

I am using Xcode 6 and I am trying to add programmatically an image to my view. Everything is fine if I load an image beloging to the project, nothing works when I try to load an image resident on some remote server.

I have tried two different way:

1) using the libray SDWEBImage

```
     UIImageView *imgg =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 250, 300, 20)];
     NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beaconLogo];
    [imgg sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgg];
```

where beaconLogo is a string containing the url of the remote image (when I debug I can see that it has the correct value).
I have imported

```
#import "uiimageview+webcache.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloader.h"
```

not sure if those are the correct headers needed. Anyway, the image is not displayed

2) I tried by using the following code that I found in some answer here on stackoverflow

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beaconLogo];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIImageView *imgg =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 250, 300, 20)];
imgg.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:imgg];
```

No image is displayed, however I can see that there is something bad going on, because if I debug, I can see that "image" is nil, this line

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

doesn't seem to have the desider effect.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post here your URL i mean `beaconLogo` String.

Comment: your code doesn't have any issue as such, post your url string, may be that's not correct.

Comment: Understand that Xcode is just a fancy editor, it is not the app you are writing.

Comment: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]` is not a good download method, it does not provide errors which it seems you need. At least use: `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`. Then `NSLog()` the error if no data is received.

Comment: your 2) is the solution i'd go for. Check the contents of your URL and see if its' getting any data at all.

Comment: Can you please log your URL or check that URL in the browser, whether image is there or not.

Comment: Zaph's solution is good, otherwise, you could try refetching if the image is nil, otherwise simply don't display it (maybe the site is down and you won't ever get the image right now)

Comment: Hello,seems that that image was corrupted in some way, the link was valid but was giving some trouble. I tried with another one and now seems to work.
Thanks to all